# How to track ERC721 token transfers?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, erc-721

Wallets and etherscan can track ERC20 tokens an account owns, but are there plans for them to track ERC721 ownership?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Toshi just announced support for ERC-20 + ERC-721.

Reference: https://blog.toshi.org/toshi-wallet-now-supports-erc20-tokens-and-erc721-collectibles-e718775895aa